# What can cause Arduino to continuously restart?

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino Uno with a 3g shield and am using a Software Serial port on pin 6, 7 and the usb port for debug. After doing well for days, now my program seems to start over and over again (I see that thanks to a println in the setup function) - I added some code, to be honest.
Any suggestion about possible reasons?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using pin 6 and 7 with SoftwareSerial, the autoreset on serial connection start does not apply.
It would if you use the "standard" 0 and 1 pin which are connected on the USB.

This kind of bug happens in many cases, normally is HW related (attached hardware use too much current, are you using an external charger or power by usb?) or because you are out of ram. Check if you have enough [Available Memory](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory)

What code did you add? You say you are experienced in C#, so did you remember to clean your garbage? C/C++ does not have a garbage collector that does that for you.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino has much less memory then you are probably used to, so if are recursively calling a function intentionally or indirectly you could run out of memory.

If you are using a lot of strings it could also use all of your memory.

Can you divide and conquer to determine specifically what routine is causing the reset?

I would start by commenting out half of the main loop and see if it still resets?

Answer (score 1):

An Arduino will reset when the usb port is reinitialized (read: usb cable replugged), and that could be due to the host computer sleeping, rebooting, or something else such as the whole usb controller restarting because another usb device was plugged in.

Comment: Thank also to you. The same note as to Rynayak answer applies also to your kind suggestion: I experience restarting while already plugged in. Thinking about memory overwrite, don't know where

Answer (score 0):

Use watchdog timer Solve above issue.And while Debug using Serial monitor keep in mind whenever you start the controller get reinitialize

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is not plugging the usb port that Arduino restarts. I see the restart while already connected: the Serial.println in the setup() gets executed over and over again. I was thinking about a memory overwrite: can it be?

Comment: It is a 5 files long code, so not so easy to post here. My starting code was Mr Britz's example https://github.com/jeanbritz/ArduinoTestScripts/tree/master/SIM5216_http_post . Only one doubt: I'm not an experienced C programmer (I have 5 years .NET experience, that's completely another world), I wonder if it is possible to cause such a behaviour, if I don't pay attention to memory usage (e.g. array index out of range) and something get corrupted.

Comment: The problem Is in checking Serial available.Since your entry condition are same that used in loop.Here loop itself like **while(1)** SO do use while loop twice. use directly entry conditions instead of twice.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I found out that it had something to do with the Sony software for my phone. Turning the software On my computer solved it, and my Arduino has been happy ever since.

The solution was found [here](https://robinelvin.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/arduino-resetting-itself-on-usb/)

> The culprit in my case was Sony Ericsson software trying to identify if the USB device was a mobile phone. Disabling this cured the problem. The moral of the story is don’t run any software which uses the USB whilst you are doing Arduino development. You can disable the reset function after you’ve finished developing if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my issue was have 10 sensors on arduino 5v output. I changed 5 of them to a separeted power with a 5v regulator and all works great.

Answer (score 0):

Power regulator might be overheating and it's turning off. Putting a small piece of metal on top of it as a heatsink might fix the problem.